# Rails 4 controller does not seem correct after scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrapping, scaffold

For training, I create a simple rails app.
Then

```
rails g scaffold Tache titre:string desc:text --skip-stylesheets
rake db:migrate
rails g bootstrap:install static
```

After that, I start the server, and I click on "Add Tache", I fill the 2 fields, and then I got this error:

param is missing or the value is empty: tach

```
   # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def tach_params
      params.require(:tach).permit(:titre, :desc)
    end
end
```

So I looked in taches_controller.rb, and I notice that tache is truncated.
If I change:

```
      params.require(:tach).permit(:titre, :desc)
```

to

```
      params.require(:tache).permit(:titre, :desc)
```

It works. And this line of code is not the only one with the last character truncated.

Example:

```
    def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @tach.update(tach_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @tach, notice: 'Tache was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @tach }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @tach.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Can you tell me why it is truncated like this ? I must have miss something but I cannot see what.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens where Rails tries to [singularize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-singularize) the plural `taches`. You can try this out in the Rails console:

```
"taches".singularize
# => "tach"
```

You can correct this behaviour by putting this in an initializer (preferably `config/initializers/inflections.rb`):

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'tache', 'taches'
end
```

Be sure to restart your Rails console and server. Then you can try again:

```
"taches".singularize
# => "tache"
```

Comment: Thanks you ! I got this idea but I forgot that "es" can be considered as plurial too.